# How to enable VRF on startup on Linux/Systemd/Networkd

Tags: linux, networking

Using systemd-networkd I've created two VRF :

File : `/etc/systemd/network/vrf20.netdev`

```
[NetDev]
Name=vrf-mpls-red
Kind=vrf
 
[VRF]
Table=20
```

File : `/etc/systemd/network/vrf30.netdev`

```
[NetDev]
Name=vrf-mpls-green
Kind=vrf
 
[VRF]
Table=30
```

Each VRF have some network interfaces associated.

After system startup, both VRF are "DOWN" :

```
3: vrf-mpls-red: <NOARP,MASTER> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:ab:58:be:29:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 minmtu 1280 maxmtu 65535 
    vrf table 20 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 
4: vrf-mpls-green: <NOARP,MASTER> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 26:a8:71:a0:9b:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 minmtu 1280 maxmtu 65535 
    vrf table 30 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
File : `/etc/systemd/network/vrf20.netdev`
```

I have to use `ip link set dev vrf-mpls-red` and `ip link set dev vrf-mpls-green` to have VRF "UP" and to have network communication between interfaces inside the same VRF.

How to configure networkd to automaticaly put VRF "UP"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need .network files to pair for your .netdev

For example 99-vrf.network with:

```
[Match]
Name=vrf-*

[Link]
ActivationPolicy=up
RequiredForOnline=no
```

Will bring up both your vrf. Also be accuracy with file naming, always use 00- 10- 90- in the start of name.

Comment: Thanks, it works with a simple copy-paste and reboot, nothing more to do.

Comment: @sébastien , use `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` for fully reload systemd network part, and `networkctl status` + `networkctl reload` for light-changes int cfg.